# How does the Lagrangian work with a magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, magnetic-moment

I was told the following Lagrangian is for a charged particle with spin moving in a constant magnetic field:
$$
L = \frac{\left ( \vec p \right ) ^2}{2m}  + \vec \mu \cdot \vec B$$

Let's just say $B$ is just constant in the $z$ direction, and not dependent on position. Then wouldn't the Lagrange equation give us $\dot p_x=0$ because the Lagrangian does not depend on $x$? This is obviously wrong because the particle will accelerate due to the Lorentz force. What mistake am I making? Or is this Lagrangian just wrong (the ones I've seen before use a vector potential)?

Comment: That’s the Lagrangian for a particle with a magnetic dipole moment but zero charge.

Comment: Lagrangians depend on generalized velocities ($\dot q$) and not on momenta ($p$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was said in the commentary by @knzhou, what you have written is the Lagrangian for a particle with magnetic moment and no charge (e.g. like neutron). Then your logic is correct: as long as magnetic field is uniform, the particle will experience no force.  The Lagrangian of a $charged$ particle in magnetic field on the other hand will read:
$$L(\vec{v}, \vec{x}) = \frac{(m\vec{v}-e\vec{A}(\vec{x}))^2}{2m} + \vec{\mu}\cdot \vec{B}$$
where $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential such that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A} = \vec{B}$. For example, for a uniform magnetic field $\vec{B} = (0,0,B)$, the vector potential can be chosen to be $\vec{A} = (0,-Bx,0)$. As you see, now the Lagrangian is explicitly coordinate-dependent, so $\dot{p_x} \neq 0$.

Comment: minor typo corrected, ( m v ...) should be  (m v ...)^2